# Expect script for ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

I has a simple expect script for sshing into a remote machine adapted from here https://serverfault.com/questions/79645/ssh-run-a-command-on-login-and-then-stay-logged-in:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set host [lrange $argv 0 0]
spawn ssh $host
expect "root"
interact
```

The only problem is that when I exit from the remote host by typing "exit", there's a 3 second hang and then I get the prompt back. I don't know much about the internals of expect, so I was wondering if somebody knows about the reason and how to avoid it.

Comment: I have tried this and found no delay after `exit` from the interactive ssh. Add `-d` flag with `expect` and post the debug information. That can help us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Here's what I see after I type exit with the -d switch:


    `interact: received eof from spawn_id exp6
    write() failed to write anything - will sleep(1) and retry...
    tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
    tty_set: raw = 5, echo = 0`

Comment: I found this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=974622

and that's my version too.